# Add button to Block toolbar: toggleFormat is undefined

Tags: block-editor

I'm try to add a custom button to the toolbar for paragraph blocks.

I followed the steps reproduced in this great tutorial:
[https://neliosoftware.com/blog/how-to-add-a-button-to-the-gutenberg-editor-using-wordpress-scripts/](https://neliosoftware.com/blog/how-to-add-a-button-to-the-gutenberg-editor-using-wordpress-scripts/?nab=0)

The button is correctly showing up and every piece of code in that project is working good.

I have some trouble to get the content updated inside the editor when the button is clicked.

I tried to follow this guidelines:
https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/format-api/3-apply-format/ but I get a console error saying that the method toggleFormat is undefined.

I share this github: **[Gutenberg Buttons](https://github.com/supergiulab/gutenberg-buttons)**, if someone can help me to fix the issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I can see what the problem is. You are not using the `onChange` properly. It comes from the `props` of the edit component:

[image]

Here you have a complete example that works:

```
registerFormatType(
    'nelio/keyboard', {
        title: __( 'Key', 'nelio' ),
        tagName: 'kbd',
        className: null,
        edit: ( { value, onChange } ) => (
            <RichTextToolbarButton
                icon="editor-removeformatting"
                title={ __( 'Key', 'nelio' ) }
                onClick={ () => onChange( toggleFormat( value, { type: 'nelio/keyboard' } ) ) }
            />
        ),
    }
);
```

Comment: Thankyou very much!